# How to get user feedback?

Tags: user-feedback

I am developing a web application, which is still in initial stages.I have put it on web for public to use.Should I use uservoice for feedback(free account)? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Probably not the best place to ask. But yes, you should use UserVoice.

Comment: Is this application being used an intranet, or publicly?  If it's being used on an intranet, you can ask people directly which might net you a lot more information.

Answer (score 3):

[GetSatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/) is the other big alternative if you're looking at "open forum" type feedback webapps, not that there probably aren't others I've never noticed. There's also more helpdesk-ish solutions out there, like [Tender](http://tenderapp.com/) for example.

Of course, you could also put up a quick 'contact us' form for the time being if you're not expecting too much traffic at the start, and keep everything in your existing issue tracker.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I use on [my website](http://pjondevelopment.50webs.com) are comments and feedback from [JS-Kit](http://js-kit.com/) a free and simple solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: +1: Excellent service, I just installed it on my website. I really like the poll.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen [UserRules](http://www.userrules.com/pricing) and it nicely fits into my application's usecase. Thr r some rich set of features that are too tempting. I personally like the seamless integration with our Issue Tracker (JIRA) to export feedback into tickets which can also be tracked within the system only.
It also allows to add custom fields in the feedback widget while collecting feedback that takes the cherry from the top.

Answer (score 2):

[UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com) - self-hosted software (PHP/MySQL), feature-rich, attractive pricing, no montly fees.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213941/best-way-to-get-user-feedback-for-web-app/3277161#3277161) on this topic for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213941/best-way-to-get-user-feedback-for-web-app), which is basically to look at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_Feedback_Management_services) (which has a comparison table).

Answer (score 1):

If you want more specific feedback (e.g. bug reports / design criticism) - you can have a look at [Usersnap](https://usersnap.com) - a feedback button with in-browser screenshot capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mail account for receiving user feedback, for one. Another free alternative is Google docs and spreadsheets, which has a free form feature that will convert the feedback you received into entries in the spreadsheet.

SurveyMonkey is another free alternative... there are many offerings in the market, what I have named is just a few.

Answer (score -1):

If you have your own web server, take a look at [VoxPopuli](http://www.eldos.com/vp/) . This is a web widget designed for hosting on your web site. It's free and open-source and it can be easily integrated into any CMS, forum system and alike.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://opensource.org/docs/osd): The first rule of open source is you can freely sell/redistribute the code. Where do you see that in voxpopuli's [license](http://www.eldos.com/licenses/ww-free.php?PRODUCT=VoxPopuli) agreement?