# Best Way to get User Feedback for Web app

Tags: iphone, testing, feedback

I am launching a iphone web app that is related to mobile searching. Currently, I am looking for users to test on this app.

What is the best way to get feedback for this app? And get users to my web app?

Thanks.

Comment: Sort of duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948268/how-to-get-user-feedback), but good answers here

Answer (score 2):

Refer Wiki:[Customer Feedback Management services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_Feedback_Management_services) a list of online services. This page has a list of free and paid tools and their comparison. These online software specialize in feedback analysis and opinion polls, etc;

Comment: This wikipedia page doesn't have a list of customer feedback management services?

Answer (score 1):

Self-hosted software:

- [UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com)

SaaS services:

- [GetSatisfaction](http://www.getsatisfaction.com)
- [UserVoice](http://www.uservoice.com)
- [UserEcho](http://www.userecho.com)
- [Copiny](http://www.copiny.com) - russian language only

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay (small amounts), one suggestion is Amazon's Mechanical Turk.

Comment: Interesting one. Have you tried to use their service? How is the quality of the feedback? Would it be a problem if my web app requires an iPhone to run?

Comment: I personally haven't used it, but we're considering it for a project I'm working on.  Obviously the more complicated the task (whether in terms of number of steps, or depth of feedback), the more you'll have to incentivize the user to complete it.  I believe you can target your questions/tasks specifically to iPhone users.  As examples, check these out - https://www.mturk.com/mturk/searchbar?selectedSearchType=hitgroups&searchWords=iphone&minReward=0.00&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

Re how to get first users:
Check out services like [Betalist](https://betalist.com) or [Launchingnext](https://launchingnext.com). There are free and allow you to get first users.

Re how to get feedback:
Check out easy-to-use feedback tools like Usersnap or Usabilla.